# using 3D-GAN create 3d outfit from multiple input customer images

Tags: deep-learning, 3d, generative-adversarial-network

I need to create 3d outfit from 2d input images.

I tried to download the codebase and dataset(2d image outfits) but i could not find it.

After surfing over the web, We found using 3D-GAN (http://3dgan.csail.mit.edu/)  we can generate 3d outfits from [2d images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hL8x4.png).

Can somebody help me how can i implement the same.

Thanks
IB